# Using ValueTuple with PackageReference on Azure Cloud Services

Tags: c#, azure, msbuild, azure-cloud-services, packagereference

I'm trying to convert my c# projects from old to new csproj style, but this breaks my Azure cloud service at runtime because the ReferenceAssembly of `System.ValueTuple.dll` is copied instead of the implementing assembly.

This is the same problem as described in this closed/abandoned [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/3699).

As my projects are currently targeting .NET 4.6.2, the problem is "solvable" by targeting .NET 4.7+, as that comes with `System.ValueTuple` and hence does not need to reference it as a NuGet package.

I would like to avoid this situation, if possible, as:

- This requires an additional deploy step to install .net 4.7+ runtimes on the worker roles, as they come with .net 4.6.2 installed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-guestos-update-matrix#family-5-releases
- This seems as "the easy way out", and I would like to know if the problem can be solved otherwise.

Additional description of the issue:

I'll use:

- `refDLL` for: `packages\system.valuetuple\4.5.0\ref\net461\System.ValueTuple.dll`, and
- `libDLL` for `packages\system.valuetuple\4.5.0\lib\net461\System.ValueTuple.dll`.

They are easily distinguishable, as `refDLL` is 40 kb and `libDLL` is 78 kb.

The actual code and complete build log file is found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kquv5voa19jfonz/AzureCloudService1.zip?dl=0

I have a solution struture as follows:

- AzureCloudService1
- WorkerRole1 (old csproj)
- WorkerRole2 (new csproj)

After building the cloud service the

- `WorkerRole1\bin\Debug` has `libDLL`.
- `WorkerRole2\bin\Debug\net461` has `libDLL`
- `AzureCloudService1\obj\Debug\WorkerRole1` has `libDLL`
- `AzureCloudService1\obj\Debug\WorkerRole2` has **`refDLL`**

From the logs, I noticed the following difference between WorkerRole1 and WorkerRole2.

WorkerRole1:

```
C:\Users\jonas\source\repos\AzureCloudService1\packages\System.ValueTuple.4.5.0\lib\net461\System.ValueTuple.dll
CopyLocal = true
FusionName = System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
HintPath = ..\packages\System.ValueTuple.4.5.0\lib\net461\System.ValueTuple.dll
ImageRuntime = v4.0.30319
MSBuildSourceProjectFile = C:\Users\jonas\source\repos\AzureCloudService1\WorkerRole1\WorkerRole1.csproj
MSBuildSourceTargetName = BuiltProjectOutputGroupDependencies
OriginalItemSpec = System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL
ReferenceAssembly = C:\Users\jonas\source\repos\AzureCloudService1\packages\System.ValueTuple.4.5.0\lib\net461\System.ValueTuple.dll
ReferenceSourceTarget = ResolveAssemblyReference
ResolvedFrom = {HintPathFromItem}
Version = 4.0.3.0
```

WorkerRole2:

```
C:\Users\jonas\.nuget\packages\system.valuetuple\4.5.0\ref\net461\System.ValueTuple.dll
CopyLocal = false
ExternallyResolved = true
FusionName = System.ValueTuple, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51
HintPath = C:\Users\jonas\.nuget\packages\system.valuetuple\4.5.0\ref\net461\System.ValueTuple.dll
ImageRuntime = v4.0.30319
MSBuildSourceProjectFile = C:\Users\jonas\source\repos\AzureCloudService1\WorkerRole2\WorkerRole2.csproj
MSBuildSourceTargetName = BuiltProjectOutputGroupDependencies
NuGetPackageId = System.ValueTuple
NuGetPackageVersion = 4.5.0
NuGetSourceType = Package
OriginalItemSpec = C:\Users\jonas\.nuget\packages\system.valuetuple\4.5.0\ref\net461\System.ValueTuple.dll
Private = false
ReferenceAssembly = C:\Users\jonas\.nuget\packages\system.valuetuple\4.5.0\ref\net461\System.ValueTuple.dll
ReferenceSourceTarget = ResolveAssemblyReference
ResolvedFrom = {HintPathFromItem}
Version = 4.0.3.0
```

After searching for other related issues on various Microsoft issue trackers, I found this one, which seems related: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1738.